# python3 install module apiclient error in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-api-python-client

I am trying to connect the `google analytics API` to my Jupyter Notebook and I am getting an error when I try to install the libraries.

```
import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools
```

Error returned:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4f9f833c28f1> in <module>()
      1 import argparse
      2 
----> 3 from apiclient.discovery import build
      4 from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apiclient'
```

I was basically using [this demo](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py) and it worked when I ran it as a python app in terminal but when I moved the code over to jupyter it started throwing that error.

I've tried:

`pip3 install --upgrade google-api-python-client` in the terminal everything is up to date

`!pip3 install google-api-python-client` in the notebook and returns everything is up to date.

I am using anaconda for local jupyter install if that makes any difference. Any ideas on how to fix this or other things to try?

Answer (score 0):

Try this other one:

```
pip install --force-reinstall google-api-python-client
```

If it doesnt work, download [the zip here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-api-python-client/downloads) and Just unzip this into your App Engine project.

Comment: I'll try pip but I'm not running an App Engine project. Jupyter Notebooks is running locally.

Comment: Didn't work, also restarted the notebook to make sure changes were going through but still getting the same error.

Comment: try this, just in case from googleapiclient.discovery import build @NicoM

Comment: mmm... rare! lets try this pip install --force-reinstall uritemplate.py, someone has a bug with that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145250/discussion-between-damian-lattenero-and-nicom).